# How do you find the sum of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was doing revision on sequences and series when I found I was unable to answer this particular question.
[image]

I have gone completely blank and would appreciate any help.
Thanks,

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ cubes is equal to the square of the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers.

Comment: Don't spend too much time thinking about the first few terms, just focus on $n(8n^2+1)$

Comment: Wait so do I just use the standard results for 8n cubed + n? @WW1

Comment: "Wait so do I just use ..." : Yes.  In fact, consider the series as $(8 + 1) + (32 + 2) + (72 + 3) + \cdots $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(8i^{2}+1)&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( 8i^{3}+i \right )\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}8i^{3}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\\
&=8\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{3}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\\
&=8\left ( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right )^{2}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\end{align*}